# a binary tree,each node has an evaluation number,how do I program a code that prints a list that maximizes the sum of eval. number

Tags: java, binary-tree, brute-force

I have a text file and a code that arranges the texts in arrays that resemble a binary tree, each node has an employee name and evaluation number in addition to the pointers. How do I implement a code that prints a list that maximizes the sum of the evaluation-based ratings of the employees, such that an employee does not attend with their immediate head.

I have to solve this by brute force, but all sources are showing recursion

Comment: A very ambiguous question, what is the evaluation-number? 
numbers, strings? 
How to evaluate? 
Number size? 
Character length?

Comment: (integers) on each node and an integer k and i have to find a subset of the nodes containing at most k nodes , that maximizes the sum of evaluations and no pair of nodes in the subset have parent-child relationship . I am supposed to utilize brute force to solve that

Comment: and the employee name is a string